# DiskLRUCache for Bitmaps (and others) in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-lru-cache, imageresizer-diskcache, diskcache

In android many image loading libraries (like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/) -- which uses 2% of the storage for disk cache, Glide) use disk cache in addition to in memory lru cache. I can understand why this might be useful for images downloaded from the network -- if the in memory cache is full, read it from disk rather than fetching them remotely -- thus avoiding network latency etc. However, if we are just reading local images on the android device itself -- do we gain anything by using a separate disk cache with the serialized bitmap data -- since the data will have to be read from the disk anyways ? Probably makes sense if your app needs a thumbnail and subsample the original image once and store it in cache ? Are there any studies showing perf gains. I have seen use of disk cache in [googles samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DisplayingBitmaps) and other [bitmap cache](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache) libraries.

Comment: Great topic. I had OutOfMemory issues when loading thumbnails from the device, when dealing with images I always use Glide or Picasso, but I've notice with Piccasso I still sometimes get Out of memory issues when dealing with large images. Would be nice if someone with more knowledge about think could answer.

Answer (score 0):

so here are some refs I found in the [AOSP docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html):

> A memory cache is useful in speeding up access to recently viewed
>   bitmaps, however you cannot rely on images being available in this
>   cache. Components like GridView with larger datasets can easily fill
>   up a memory cache. Your application could be interrupted by another
>   task like a phone call, and while in the background it might be killed
>   and the memory cache destroyed. Once the user resumes, your
>   application has to process each image again.
>
> A disk cache can be used in these cases to persist processed bitmaps
>   and help decrease loading times where images are no longer available
>   in a memory cache. Of course, fetching images from disk is slower than
>   loading from memory and should be done in a background thread, as disk
>   read times can be unpredictable.